# Are polynomial rings finitely generated modules over the base ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Consider $R[X_1,...,X_n]$. Clearly it is a natural $R$-module.

> Is it true that $R[X_1,...,X_n]$ is a finitely generated $R$-module? If it is, then every its ideal is a finitely generated $R$-module too right?

For me the answer is yes for both questions since every element $f\in R[X_1,...,X_n]$ has the form $\sum_{i=0}^nr_iX^i$ with $r_0,...,r_n\in R$, so the set of generators is $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$.

Thank you.

Comment: The annoying pedant in me feels obliged to point out that $R[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$ _is_ (quite boringly) a finitely generated $R$-module if $R = \{0\}$.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning though that $R[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ is finitely generated as a module over itself iff $R$ is finitely generated as a module over itself - Hilbert Basis Theorem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is **NOT** finitely generated as an $R$-module. It is finitely generated as an algebra, though. Every element is not of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n r_i X^i$. The correct statement would be that every element is of the form $\sum\limits_{I=(i_1,\dots,i_n)} r_I X_1^{i_1}\cdots X_n^{i_n}$. All the monomials $X_1^{i_1} \cdots X_n^{i_n}$ are linearly independent, and so the generating set (as an $R$-module) is infinite.

Comment: +1 and also, to address this: *If it is, then every its ideal is a finitely generated $R$− module too right?* I realize your question is in terms of polynomial rings, but I wanted to say that the idea doesn't hold in general. If you take any nonNoetherian ring $R$, $R$ is a cyclic module, but it has non-finitely generated submodules. @richard

Comment: See the answer below by Moises. It is because every element is a "polynomial expression" in the variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$.

Comment: If the ring is finite,then it is finitely generated right?

Answer (score 7):

For a module $M$ to be generated over $R$ by some elements $\{a_1,\ldots ,a_n\}$, by definition every element in $M$ has to be a **linear** combination of the generating elements, that is, every $m\in M$ is of the form$$m=\sum_i r_ia_i$$for some $r_i\in R$. Therefore, the variables $X_i$ only generate the polynomials of degree 1 in $R[X_1,\ldots ,X_n]$.

What you are looking for is for finite generation **as an $R$-algebra**, which means that every element in $R[X_1,\ldots ,X_n]$ is a polynomial in the $X_i$'s with coefficients in $R$.